# Do not change the checked in the second and third levels in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why in the following code, when sending the ID, the value of the checked object in the second and third levels does not change to true or false !!!
**But it works well in the first round**

```
const terms = [
   {
      "term_id":21,
      "name":"Clothing",
      "checked":false,
      "children":[
         {
            "term_id":24,
            "name":"Accessories",
            "checked":false,
            "children":[
               {
                  "term_id":25,
                  "name":"Scarf",
                  "checked":false,
                  "children":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]


  const setChecked = (data, id) => {
    let newTerms = [];
    data.map((item, key) => {
      if (item.children && item.children.length) {
        newTerms.push({
          term_id: item.term_id,
          name: item.name,
          checked: item.term_id == id ? !item.checked : item.checked,
          children: item.children ? item.children : [],
        });
        setChecked(item.children, id);
      } else {
        //item.checked = !item.checked;
        newTerms.push({
          term_id: item.term_id,
          name: item.name,
          checked: item.term_id == id ? !item.checked : item.checked,
          children: item.children ? item.children : [],
        });
      }
    });
    return newTerms;
  };
```

Works well with first level ID ==========>  setChecked(terms, 21);

But it does not work with second or third level ID or later =========> setChecked(terms, 25);

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your "newTerms" variable as a global variable, because each iteration of your function creates a new emtpy array for your output.

Comment: Yes that's right,  
But there is another problem,  And is added to the number of arrays! 
The output of this function: [{"term_id":21,"name":"Clothing","checked":false,"children":[{"term_id":24,"name":"Accessories","checked":false,"children":[{"term_id":25,"name":"Scarf","checked":false,"children":[]}]}]},{"term_id":24,"name":"Accessories","checked":false,"children":[{"term_id":25,"name":"Scarf","checked":false,"children":[]}]},{"term_id":25,"name":"Scarf","checked":true}]